# php preg_replace remove thousand separator in a string

Tags: php, regex

there have a long articles, I want only remove `thousand separator`, not a comma.

```
$str = "Last month's income is 1,022 yuan, not too bad.";
//=>Last month's income is 1022 yuan, not too bad.

preg_replace('#(\d)\,(\d)#i','???',$str);
```

How to write the regex patterns? Thanks

Comment: Just beware that if a user makes a silly mistake in a list, you might get a problem: `He did it 1,2 and 3 times` (missing space - it would turn into 12 and 3 times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the [`preg_replace` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) you can see that you can write captures back in the replacement string using `$n`:

```
preg_replace('#(\d),(\d)#','$1$2',$str);
```

Note that there is no need to escape the comma, or to use `i` (as there are not letters in the pattern).

An alternative (and probably more efficient) way is to use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). These are not included in the match, so they don't have to written back:

```
preg_replace('#(?<=\d),(?=\d)#','',$str);
```

Answer (score 6):

If the simplified rule "Match any comma that lies directly between digits" is good enough for you, then

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\d),(?=\d)/','',$str);
```

should do.

You could improve it by making sure that exactly three digits follow:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\d),(?=\d{3}\b)/','',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `(\d)` is represented by `$1`, the second `(\d)` by `$2`. Therefore the solution is to use something like this:

```
preg_replace('#(\d)\,(\d)#','$1$2',$str);
```

Actually it would be better to have 3 numbers behind the comma to avoid causing havoc in lists of numbers:

```
preg_replace('#(\d)\,(\d{3})#','$1$2',$str);
```