# What's the best way to validate numbers with comma as decimal separator?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

In a Laravel app, I have a form on which I need to validate numbers with a comma as the decimal separator. For the moment, it only works with a point because my validation rule is:

```
$rules = [
    'amount' => 'numeric|min:0',
];
```

What’s the best method :

- Keep the rule and replace comma with point before validation ? Is there a before_validation observer or something like this ?
- Build a custom validation rule ? french_numeric for example ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Laravel supports `regex` pattern in validation rule so you can use the given pattern to match something like `12,365.00` and it's recommended to use an array instead of pipe when using regular expressions as a rule

```
$rules = array('amount' => array('match:/^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]+$/'));
```

[Check this link.](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1139) Also, if you want to remove the commas for any reason then [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100821/php-preg-replace-remove-thousand-separator-in-a-string).

Comment: how to use this? lack of answer cause it gave me `Method [validateMatch] does not exist. `

Comment: @StormSpirit: Replace `match` with `regex` and it should work.

Comment: Update: The following will match negative numbers as well: 'regex:/^-?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]+$/' i.e. 10 and -10 will both be validated.

Comment: But you can't use the min rule properly when you use a regex, because it would take the number of characters and not the numeric value. That poses a problem to me right now. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: I created a custom rule as a solution for numeric size validation. See answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Building on the excellent answer from The Alpha, here is a code snippet to make a float validation configurable.

Add this snippet to the `boot()` function in your `AppServiceProvider` class (tested with Laravel 5.4):

```
Validator::extend('float', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $thousandsSeparator = env('APP_NUMBER_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR') == '.' ? '\\' . env('APP_NUMBER_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR') : env('APP_NUMBER_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR');
    $commaSeparator = env('APP_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATOR') == '.' ? '\\' . env('APP_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATOR') : env('APP_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATOR');
    $regex = '~^[0-9]{1,3}(' . $thousandsSeparator . '[0-9]{3})*' . $commaSeparator . '[0-9]+$~';
    $validate = preg_match($regex, $value);

    if ($validate === 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Your .env-file would have those two lines:

```
APP_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATOR="."
APP_NUMBER_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR=","
```

And your rule would look like this:

```
$rules = [
    'amount' => 'float|min:0',
];
```

Note: I'm only escaping the `.` correctly. If you are going to use charaters that have special meaning in regex syntax (like * or +) you have to escape them too.

But since a **float number** like `550*345,00 (550,345.00)` or `57+44 (57.44)` wouldn't make sense I've ignored this issue.

Kind regards

Comment: The min rule would evaluate the number of characters in your solution, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else had the problem of validating the numeric size of the input after the regex check from the solution, I post my solution here. I needed it for *max* though unlike in the question, but it can be easily adapted for *min*.

I created a new rule object as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects

The idea of injecting parameters comes from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384976/11854580

The *toFloat* method is a user contribution on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Utils\NumberUtils;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class NumericMaxForString implements Rule
{
    private $maxValue;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($maxValue)
    {
        $this->maxValue = $maxValue;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $numericValue = NumberUtils::toFloat($value);
        return $numericValue <= $this->maxValue;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute may not be greater than ' . $this->maxValue . '.';
    }
}
```