# Laravel Time regex validation

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am working on a time regex (24 hours) in laravel, but cant get it working:

```
'Time' => 'regex:/^\d(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$rules = array(
    'time' => array('regex:/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/')
);
```

> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify
>   rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the
>   regular expression contains a pipe character.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting:`preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found`

Comment: It works, tested in my localhost. Make sure you have used `array` and also notice I've changed the `pattern`. You may also change the delimiters to `#...#`, but i should work with `/`.

Comment: [Also check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628868/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-numbers-with-comma-as-decimal-separator/17630122#17630122).