# Laravel preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']'

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-validation

Im wokring on Laravel 4.2. Im trying to use validator to validate a name field with regex here is my rule below:

```
public static $rules_save = [
    'name'      => 'required|regex:/[XI0-9/]+/|unique:classes'
];
```

But as soon as I call the rule to be validated an error is thrown see below:

```
preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']'
```

In the following location:

```
protected function validateRegex($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $this->requireParameterCount(1, $parameters, 'regex');

        return preg_match($parameters[0], $value); // **ON THIS LINE**
    }
```

Comment: Just replace `/]` with `]` if you want to only match `X`,`I` and digits. Or if you want to include `/` to the character class: `\/]`. What are your requirements?

Comment: @stribizhev I need the / as a part of the regex.

Comment: Then try `'name'      => 'required|regex:/[XI0-9\/]+/|unique:classes'`. Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you need to include a `/` into the character class, you need to either esacpe it:

```
'name'      => 'required|regex:/[XI0-9\/]+/|unique:classes'
                                      ^
```

Or use other [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by *delimiters*. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (`/`), hash signs (`#`) and tildes (`~`).

Comment: Also, check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628868/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-numbers-with-comma-as-decimal-separator/17630122#17630122)if that still does not work.

Comment: Just curious: you posted another question regarding the pipes, does my answer really worked, or did you have to rearrange it like `public static $rules_save = [
    'name' => ['required', 'regex:/[XI0-9\/]+/','unique:classes'],
];`?

Answer (score 2):

As the first poster(stribizhev) pointed out, you need to escape the forward slash `/`, and this is because the backslash `/` is used as a delimiter in that pattern. Therefore, making it to act like a special character within the character class.

Therefore your pattern should be like this

```
/[XI0-9\/]+/
```

But if you make use of other delimiters e.g `#`, then there would be no need to escape the forward slash.

```
#[XI0-9/]+#
```

here, i didn't escape the forward slash because i used `#` as a delimiter

Hope this helps.

For more info, check out the link posted by stribizhev.