# How to pass parameters in Laravel Rule?

Tags: laravel

I would like to move this code to the App\Rule:

```
//Currently in class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

Validator::extend('empty_if', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   return ($value != '' && request($parameters[0]) != '') ? false : true;
});
```

So that it should be this:

```
//in: App\Rules\EmptyIf

public function passes($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
   return ($value != '' && request($parameters[0]) != '') ? false : true;
}
```

But my problem is, that I cannot pass $parameters with

```
Validator::extend('empty_if', 'App\Rules\EmptyIf@passes');
```

How would you pass parameters to Laravel Rule?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, can you provide a bit more detail?

Comment: @Jonathon I'm sorry now I edited my post, perhaps its clearer now. If not tell me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you need correctly you don't need to extend the validator.

You seem to have class:

```
class EmptyIf extends Rule {
      public function passes($attribute, $value, $parameters) { }
}
```

Then you can just use this as:

```
$this->validate($data, [ "entry" => [ new EmptyIf() ] ]);
```

You might be able to do both using:

```
Validator::extend('empty_if', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    return (new EmptyIf())->passes($atribute, $value, $parameters);
 });
```

Comment: So my thing is that I want to use it normally in Rule, like so: sometimes|nullable|empty_if:about_image|max:200|url'. 
So I need to extend the validation, but I cannot get the variable to work $parameters, because it only passes to parameters ($attribute, $value)

Comment: You made a choice. Either extends `Rule` and use it as an object in a rules array, or extend the validator and use it as a string. You might be able to combine them by doing the new instance within the callback but the `Classname@FunctionName` is not really a valid way define that

Comment: That is a pity. Sometimes ago I watched a video by laracast and he did the exact thing:  Validator::extend('spamfree', 'App\Rules\SpamFree@passes');

Comment: This works well, but now I need to get the parameters for empty_if:{parameter[0]}, but can't get it :(

Comment: There does not seem to be any support of parameters when using a class as a validation rule. If you use the validator extend method it seems to work just fine though even if that means you'll need to create a new instance of the class. You could probably raise a feature request in github

Answer (score 19):

Here is a simpler and updated way of accomplishing this, without extending the validator. You can access the passed param in the Rule's constructor, so just set a globally scoped variable and now you can reference it inside of the passes() method. You could even use the same approach to have the value in the validator message.

The validate call:

```
case 'measurement':
 $request->validate([
   'updates.*.value' => [
   new Measurement('foo-bar'),
   ],
 ]);
 break;
```

The Rule:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Measurement implements Rule
{
/**
 * Create a new rule instance.
 *
 * @param $param
 */
public function __construct($param)
{
    $this->type = $param;
}

public $type;
/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param string $attribute
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param array $parameters
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    dd($this->type, 'params');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When using a rule class with required `$parameters`, you'll get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:
Declaration of App\Rules\AgeAt::passes($attribute, $value, $parameters)
must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule::passes($attribute, $value)
```

You can simply make that `$parameters` optional, and you will get the parameters passed in Laravel 5.5+ automatically:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value, $parameters = [])
{
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this has changed since Laravel 5.5 but it does not automatically pass in the `$parameters` to this function. `$parameters` is empty.

Comment: It's working on laravel 10

Answer (score 6):

You can pass parameters with **constructor** in **Rule**

```
public function __construct($params)
{
    $this->params = $params;
}
```

Then access parameters in **passes** method

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
  //access params with $this->params
}
```

Comment: Another best, correct, and working answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by passing the parameter(s) into the constructor for your `Rule`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmptyIf implements Rule
{
    public $otherParameter;

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (Request::get($this->otherParameter) != '') {
            return ($value == '');
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute cannot be empty if ' . $this->otherParameter . ' is set';
    }
}
```

And in the service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Rules\EmptyIf;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Validator::extend('empty_if', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $rule = new EmptyIf($parameters[0]);

            return $rule->passes();
        });
    }
}
```

So now you can use the string form in your validator:

```
'sometimes|nullable|empty_if:about_image|max:200|url'
```