# Laravel validation `exists` Or some fixed value like "other"

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a `select` dropdown with options from the database table `options`. The values are as:

```
cheese
pepper
onions
other
```

The option `"other"` is not in the database, but when a user selects that they can enter a new option. I want to  validate the input such that the options either `exists` in the `options` table or is of value `"other"`. How can I create such validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run command to create a custom rule. It will create a file in Rules folder.

```
php artisan make: rule CheckExistance
```

Then update the function of this file like below:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value){
    $optionExist=Option::where('option_name',$value)->exists();
     if ($optionExist|| $value=="other") {
         return true;
    }
}
```

And print error like below:

```
public function message(){
    return 'The :attribute already exists.';
}
```

And finally use validation in controller like below:

```
$request->validate([
     'inputName'=>['required', new CheckExistance()],
]);
```

Comment: Can this be extended to other models? So have a common `CheckExistenceOrOther` function where we can pass in the model/database table and it will check in that?

Comment: Yes, this rule can be used in any controller.

Comment: You can also pass Model name as parameter and use it for query here is you answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174006/how-to-pass-parameters-in-laravel-rule

Comment: How can you use Model name to perform the query? For the above example you provided `Option::` would need to change if it was a different model.

Comment: You can also [extend the already existing Exists](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-column-name) rule, and add the constraint that other is also a valid value.